# Save one date into two datetime columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got two datetime columns in my Schedule model: `starts_at` and `ends_at`.

Requirements: When creating/updating a schedule, user will see:

- 1 select menu for choosing a date
- 1 select menu for choosing a start time (hour:minute)
- 1 select menu for choosing an end time (hour:minute)

I'd like to let the user choose the date from a single select menu. Then save the date in the two datetime columns. I only want the date to be the same, not the time.

My current code makes the user input the date on both the datetime attributes, which is cumbersome:

```
<%= f.label :starts_at %>
<%= f.datetime_select :starts_at %>

<%= f.label :ends_at %>
<%= f.datetime_select :ends_at %>
```

I tried this:

```
# view
<%= f.date_select :starts_at, order: [:day, :month, :year] %>
<%= f.time_select :starts_at, ignore_date: true %>
<%= f.time_select :ends_at %>

# controller
def update
  @partner  = Partner.find(params[:partner_id])
  @schedule = @partner.schedules.find(params[:id])
  @klass    = Klass.find(schedule_params[:klass_id])
  @schedule.activity_id = @klass.activity_id

  date = Date.civil(schedule_params["starts_at(1i)"].to_i, schedule_params["starts_at(2i)"].to_i, schedule_params["starts_at(3i)"].to_i)
  @schedule.ends_at = date

  @schedule.update(schedule_params)
end

private

  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(:klass_id, :starts_at, :ends_at, :quantity)
  end
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. But the code is quite ugly.

```
def update
  @partner  = Partner.find(params[:partner_id])
  @schedule = @partner.schedules.find(params[:id])
  @klass    = Klass.find(schedule_params[:klass_id])

  @schedule.city_id     = @partner.city_id
  @schedule.activity_id = @klass.activity_id
  @schedule.klass_id    = schedule_params[:klass_id]
  @schedule.quantity    = schedule_params[:quantity]

  @schedule.starts_at = DateTime.civil(
    schedule_params["starts_at(1i)"].to_i, schedule_params["starts_at(2i)"].to_i,
    schedule_params["starts_at(3i)"].to_i,
    schedule_params["starts_at(4i)"].to_i, schedule_params["starts_at(5i)"].to_i
  )

  @schedule.ends_at = DateTime.civil(
    schedule_params["starts_at(1i)"].to_i, schedule_params["starts_at(2i)"].to_i,
    schedule_params["starts_at(3i)"].to_i,
    schedule_params["ends_at(4i)"].to_i, schedule_params["ends_at(5i)"].to_i
  )

  @schedule.save
end

private

def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit(:klass_id, :starts_at, :ends_at, :quantity)
end
```

I'm still open to anyone who can come up with better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually missing the parameter since it's not in the form.

Shouldn't the view look like that?

```
<%= f.date_select :starts_at, order: [:day, :month, :year] %>
<%= f.time_select :starts_at, ignore_date: true %>
<%= f.date_select :ends_at, order: [:day, :month, :year] %>
<%= f.time_select :ends_at, ignore_date: true %>
```

Comment: But if I do that then there will be 2 select inputs for the date. I just want one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to make a comment because I do not have enough reputation points, but wouldn't the following work?

```
@schedule.ends_at = @schedule.starts_at
```

Comment: This will make both the start time and end time the same.

Comment: @i.am.noob ... That's what you said you wanted: "I'd like to let the user choose the date from a single select menu. Then save the date in those two datetime columns." What you're missing is the part where you want *only* the date to be the same, not the time.

Comment: @DaveNewton But this one will overwrite the time on column `ends_at`.

Comment: @i.am.noob So only ask the user for the time once, and the date twice.

Comment: @DaveNewton No, I want the user to input one date for the schedule then different start time and end time.

Comment: @i.am.noob Whichever; I think you can extrapolate my backwards answer to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using [the Rails DateTime change method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-change) on `@schedule.starts_at` to set the time from the `:ends_at` value.

Like:

```
@schedule.ends_at = @schedule.starts_at.change(
  hour: schedule_params[:ends_at].hour, 
  min: schedule_params[:ends_at].min, 
  sec: 0
)
```

Or something like that anyway...